# How to access information from a superclass and subclass?

Tags: java

What I am trying to do is access information (variables, methods, etc) from a superclass and it's subclasses.

If, what I know about inheritance is right, by accessing the superclass we have access to it's subclasses by default. So I am thinking that I only need to be able to access the parent (super) class.

But how do I do that?

I am not going to post all the code up here, and that will turn this post into 3 pages.

The superclass is just a general code to create a contact and the class that needs to access the superclass is a class that creates an arraylist and records each contact in the arraylist.

I am not trying to get the code written for me, but all the help to understand how this will work, will be greatly appreciated.

To keep this short, I won't post the subclasses unless needed.

Contacts (Superclass):

```
public class Contacts
{
    protected String fname;
    protected String lname;
    protected String email;
    protected String phone;

    public Contacts(String fname, String lname, String email, String phone)
    {
        this.fname=fname;
        this.lname=lname;
        this.email=email;
        this.phone=phone;

    }

    public String getfname()
    {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setfname(String first)
    {
        this.fname=first;       
    }

    public String getlname()
    {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setlname(String last)
    {
        this.lname=last;
    }

    public String getemail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setemail(String e)
    {
        this.email=e;
    }

    public String getphone()
    {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setphone(String num)
    {
        this.phone=num;
    }

    public String getFullName()
    {
        String full=fname+" "+lname;
        return full;
    }
```

I haven't done much on this code because I have been trying to figure it out without really knowing where to start. I do not think the arguments should be null, I just included those to satisfy the evil compiler.

Addressbook:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class AddressBook
{
    Contacts enteredContact = new Contacts(null, null, null, null);
}
```

Here is one of the subclasses to get an idea of what is included.

Friends (subclass):

```
public class Friend extends Contacts
{
    private String dob;

    /**
     * Constructs a new Friend object. (Insert any further description that is needed)
     * @param fname
     * @param lname
     * @param email
     * @param phone
     */
    public Friend(String fname, String lname, String email, String phone)
    {
        super(fname, lname, email, phone);
    }

    /**
     * @return the dob
     */
    public String getDob()
    {
        return dob;
    }

    /**
     * @param dob the dob to set
     */
    public void setDob(String dob)
    {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return fname+", "+lname+", "+email+", "+phone+", "+dob;
    }

}
```

Comment: Any protected or public fields or methods will be available to the subclass and you call/access them the same as any other available field or method.

Comment: I love how some will down grade a post just to boost your own personal ego. Why don't you add a comment saying why this doesn't show any personal effort. Because every character of these classes was written by me, and you can't get more "personal" or more of my "effort" than that!

Answer (score 1):

> If what I know about inheritance is right, by accessing the superclass
>   you have access to it's subclasses by default.So I'm thinking I only need to be able to access the parent (super) class.

No , by accessing the superclass you have access to only those methods of sub-class which is overridden by sub-class . The methods which the sub-class creates for own even if it is public couldn't be accessed by the object of superclass.

Answer (score 1):

Use `super` function/keyword to access parent class. You can call a parent method like this

```
super.methodName();
```

To access parent constructor, you can do it in the following way using `super()` method.

```
super(null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

If a class extends a superclass, it inherits all of its members. The non-`private` ones it can access directly.

FYI you can use the `super()` constructor to initialise the fields.

```
public class AddressBook {

    public AddressBook(String fname, String lname, String email, String phone) {
        super(null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If what I know about inheritance is right, by accessing the superclass
>   you have access to it's subclasses by default.

No, this is backwards.  By accessing the subclass, you have access to the fields of the superclass, limited to the visibility and finality of the field.  You can use `super()` to access them as you need to.

Think of inheritance like a family tree.  The superclass is your parent.  Your parents can't access any of your private fields, but you've inherited quite a few of them from yours.

Comment: So by another class "marrying" a subclass(child) the class then inherits the functions of the subclass and its parent class?

Comment: You can't have multiple inheritance, but you can get around this with interfaces - contracts enforced at compile time that specify what methods will be overridden.  My example is a more linear family tree - you inherit from your parent, who inherits from their parent, all the way up to `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a basic misunderstanding of what superclass and subclass are.

It seems to me that you're under the impression that the subclasses of Contacts are fname, lname, etc?

These are called members, or more properly in this case: instance members.

A subclass would be a class which extends Contacts, like so:

```
public class ContactsSubclass extends Contacts {
...
}
```

Comment: I don't know what makes you say that, but my subclasses are friends and businessassociate. Which start are seperate classes that i didn't include because it would greatly lengthen the post. But both subclasses do start out just like you posted.

Comment: Sorry, no code and trying to access subclass members from a superclass lead to that conclusion.

Comment: just added one of the subclass codes if you want to see if I did it right. At this point, im not very confident that those are even correct.

Comment: Looks good to me, but here's the thing: Contact contact = new Friend(...); is cool, what with polymorphism and all, however, String dob = contact.getDob(); will fail because Contact doesn't have the subclass method getDob() and knows nothing of it.

Comment: So would I call my 2 subclasses? and I'll get all overrides from the subclasses plus my methods from the parent class?

Comment: Yes, eg: Friend friend = new Friend(...); String fname = friend.getFname(); is valid. But they're not overrides, they're simply inherited from the parent - override would be if you redefined a superclass method in a subclass by using the same method signature.